# asp.net update pane will not fire event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to implement an update panel on my web page.  when I add this, everything works fine:

```
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Label2.Text = Date.Now.ToString
    End Sub
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <fieldset>
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>

  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="289px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                        Width="663px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem comes when I try to do some stuff on the on_load event of the application.  in the code behind, i try to do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
    ....a function that produces a very long xml string
        Me.TextBox1.Text ="<f"
    End If
End Sub
```

This will cause the event to not occur.  If i change the `"<"` from the string, all is well.  why cant I have `"<"` in my strings?  This is important because i wont allow me to put an xml string in the text box.

any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&lt<` rather than `<`

Comment: no, this does not work.  even after using Server.HtmlEncode to encode the string, it still causes the update panel to not work.  the string that i am printing to the text box is a large xml document (an xml reponse from the linkedin API) so, i dont have control over what is in the string.  there could be extraneous "<" or other characters the update panel does not like.  I would rather know what the cause of the problem is and fix that.

Comment: What is the average length of `Me.TextBox1.Text` ?

Comment: the length is rather long.  close to 8000 lines.  i edited the above code to show where the textbox is

Comment: is your textbox's textmode is set to "multiline"  ?

Comment: try removing the readonly property. if it works then just use the `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");` after assigning the value of textbox

Comment: check if your string variable actually contains anything. If it contains anything check its length